# Can I force Apache and PHP to use lowercase/uppercase filenames?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am developing under Windows and need to use upper/lowercase filenames in my PHP project.
Is there some way to force Apache+PHP (XAMPP) to respect difference between upper & lowercase characters in filenames? My production server is Linux, so I always end up with some links not working.

Comment: Do you want to create files using a PHP script or manually?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an Apache or PHP issue. You're running Windows, so you're probably using NTFS as the file system on your hard drive. NTFS is, by default, case insensitive. That means that you can't have both "myfile.txt" and "mYfIlE.tXt".

Apparently, [you can change this](https://superuser.com/questions/266110/how-do-you-make-windows-7-fully-case-sensitive-with-respect-to-the-filesystem). I wouldn't (software that expects case insensitivity may break).

Run a virtual machine with Linux on it. Use that as your development server.

Comment: Running VM with Linux is the best solution in my opinion. Of course you can always try to keep in mind the case of letters ;) I develop on Windows and use Linux on prod servers and don't have issues with letter case - just be consistent and create you code case-sensitive :)

Comment: I have several virtual machines running under my PC, but it is more convenient to develop under Windows in my case.
 What I would like to achieve is Apache/PHP doing "it's own" case-sensitivity. I though, that maybe there is some setting to do that.

Comment: PHP and Apache can't change how NTFS works. You can still develop under Windows: Just run the *server* under Linux and your development tools under Windows. Then set your editor to 'upload' (with FTP or SSL/SFTP) or make a shared folder in the VM that both OSes can access. Then use SMB ("Network Locations"). If you use SMB to access an EXT3 or EXT4 share, case insensitivity *should* work.