# PHP form : answers not showing

Tags: php, forms

I'm new to programming and tried to make a simple form just to test things out. The thing is, when I click on the send button, it only shows the text and it doesn't show the data...

Here is the form in the HTML file:

```
<FORM ACTION="FORM.PHP" METHOD="POST">
<P> 
Ton nom: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Tonnom" /> <br />
Espace test: <INPUT TYPE="TEST" NAME="Espacetest" />
</P>

<P>
Est-ce que ce site s'affiche correctement ?
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="AFFICHAGE" VALUE="OUI" CHECKED="CHECKED" /> Oui
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="AFFICHAGE" VALUE="NON" /> Non 
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="AFFICHAGE" VALUE="PAS SÛR" /> Pas sûr 
</P>

<P>
Des commentaires ? <BR />
<TEXTAREA NAME="COMMENTAIRES" ROWS="10" COLS="40"></TEXTAREA>
</P>

<P>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="GO!"></P>
</FORM>
```

And here's the PHP file linked to it:

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
<META CHARSET="UTF-8">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
Ton nom est: <?php echo $_POST['Tonnom']; ?><BR />
Dans l'espace test, tu as écris: <?php echo $_POST['Espacetest']; ?><BR />
<BR />

Est-ce que ce site s'affiche correctement ? <?php echo $_POST['AFFICHAGE']; 
?><BR />
<BR />

Commentaires:<BR />
<?php echo $_POST['COMMENTAIRES']; ?>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Here's the only thing that shows up when I click on the send button:

[image]

I double-checked and the php file's name is really '' FORM.PHP '' .
It's hosted through 000webhost's file manager, which does support PHP.

If anybody could help I would be thankful because I'm clueless.

Comment: Hard to say, 1st guess would be the destination file is named lowercase but in your form is upper case

Comment: No I checked it and it's in upper case so that's not the issue

Comment: Read up on XSS and how to prevent it before you put this live.

Comment: In the top of your file, add `var_dump($_POST);` and check what it contains.

Comment: Have you got the file form.php in the same folder as your HTML file?

Comment: @Oqhax - The OP sees the static text in that file so it does load it.

Comment: The HTML is seen in the file, but if the HTML inputs do not show up when printing them in PHP, it could be caused because the HTML and PHP files are in different directories.

Comment: They are stored in the same directory. I read a bit about XSS and I do intend to protect my code before making my website public :) var_dump($POST); doesn't make anything show up

Comment: Did you do `var_dump($POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)`?  Make sure it has the underscore.  If that was just a typo in your comment and you did include the underscore, open dev tools (F12) in your browser, check the Network tab and make sure that the HTTP request after submitting the form (clicking 'Go!') is a POST request.

Comment: Are you running apache?

Comment: ($POST) was just a typo :) The problem is now solved thanks to Magnus, but thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File extensions in Apache (and probably on other web servers) are case sensitive by default.

Change your file name from `FORM.PHP` to `form.php` (the important part is the `.php`).

You can see that your `FORM.PHP` is rendered as pure HTML by right clicking on the page and choose "view source". You should then see your actual PHP-code printed out.

The reason you don't see it directly on the page is because the browser renders it as HTML-tags (because of the opening `<` and closing `>` wrapped around the PHP-statements)

Comment: That was it! Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

1) if you want to check php is work or not in your local server or live server so add this code

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

in your php if php is work so this function will work.

2) i think you will refresh page after click on the Go button. so not display a code in browser.
i check your 2 code in my local pc so your html code and php code work perfectly.
i fill a form and click on the go button so display a content

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an HTML file and a PHP file, one could put the entire code in one file **form.php** and display the inputted data or else the form on error.  The code uses a **here doc** to display the results. The critical piece missing from the OP's code is server-side validation which I include in this example:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['SUBMITTED']) && $_POST['SUBMITTED'] == 'GO!' ){
  $error = 0;
  $clean['Tonnom'] =  ctype_alnum($_POST['Tonnom'])?  $_POST['Tonnom'] : '';
  if ($clean['Tonnom'] == '') $error++;

  $clean['Espacetest'] = ctype_alnum($_POST['Espacetest'])?  $_POST['Espacetest'] : '';
  if ($clean['Espacetest'] == '') $error++;

  if ( $_POST['AFFICHAGE'] == 'OUI' || $_POST['AFFICHAGE'] == 'NON' || $_POST['AFFICHAGE'] == 'PAS SÛR') {
          // data is what is expected
          $clean['AFFICHAGE'] = $_POST['AFFICHAGE'];
  }
  else
  {
   // somebody messed with this form field, so:
      $clean['AFFICHAGE'] == '';
      $error++;
      // redisplay form and/or provide error message
  }

  $clean['COMMENTAIRES'] = ctype_alnum($_POST['COMMENTAIRES'])?  $_POST['COMMENTAIRES'] : '';
  if ($clean['COMMENTAIRES'] == '') $error++;
    // if any data results in empty string decide about error messages and whether you
    // want to throw an exception 
  if ($error > 0) { 
       header("Location: form.php");
  }

echo <<<"FOOBAR"
Ton nom est: {$clean['Tonnom']}<BR />
Dans l'espace test, tu as écris: {$clean['Espacetest']}<BR />
<BR />

Est-ce que ce site s'affiche correctement ? {$clean['AFFICHAGE']} 
<BR />
<BR />

Commentaires:<BR />
   {$clean['COMMENTAIRES']}
FOOBAR;
exit();   
}
?>

<FORM ACTION="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" METHOD="POST">
<P> 
Ton nom: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Tonnom" /> <br />
Espace test: <INPUT TYPE="TEST" NAME="Espacetest" />
</P>

<P>
Est-ce que ce site s'affiche correctement ?
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="AFFICHAGE" VALUE="OUI" CHECKED="CHECKED" /> Oui
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="AFFICHAGE" VALUE="NON" /> Non 
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="AFFICHAGE" VALUE="PAS SÛR" /> Pas sûr 
</P>

<P>
Des commentaires ? <BR />
<TEXTAREA NAME="COMMENTAIRES" ROWS="10" COLS="40"></TEXTAREA>
</P>

<P>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" name="SUBMITTED" VALUE="GO!"></P>
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Setting the form's ACTION attribute to `echo htmlentities( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );` will redirect the submitted page to form.php and avoids any PHP_SELF exploits such as XSS; see [here](http://form.guide/php-form/php-form-action-self.html).

Observe that it is unwise to use submitted data without first validating it. The validation code of course may be tailored to one's liking as regards more in depth validation as well as modifying the error handling.  Everyone will hopefully get the main idea of not using submitted data until you know that it is safe to use.

Incidentally, if you're running Windows with NTFS, then file names are case insensitive, so Apache in that environment will recognize FORM.PHP as a PHP file per discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853550/can-i-force-apache-and-php-to-use-lowercase-uppercase-filenames).

Also, for some reason the foreign lettering of 'PAS SÛR' only showed up correctly in Google Chrome, once I got rid of the meta tag specifying UTF-8 and saved the file with ANSI encoding.

Lastly, I gave the submit input a name of "submitted", so that the code can know when a form has been submitted.